# How to set Ui:Field name for HTML <tr> tag (not Google Widget)?

Tags: gwt, uibinder

I want to set Ui:Field name for HTML  tag (not Google Widget), something like this:

in my UiBinder file

```
<g:HTMLPanel>
   <table> <tr ui:field="myRow"><td>Test</td></tr></table>
</g:HTMLPanel>
```

And my View.java

```
@UiField Tr myRow;
```

Can we do this? how to do it properly?

I also want to hide the `Tr` after clicking hideRow button & how to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your Java, list it as

```
@UiField
TableRowElement myRow;
```

or just as

```
@UiField
Element myRow;
```

This is documented at http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder.html#Hello_World - see the `SpanElement` called nameSpan or the `DivElement` called root.

Edit to answer hiding issue added after question was posted:

There isn't a built-in way to hide an `Element`, but you can manipulate the element in GWT/Java the same as you would in JS, something like this:

```
myRow.getStyle().setDisplay(Display.NONE);
```

Other ways to set this include `visibility:hidden`, or just removing it from its parent element.

Comment: This is a good answer. You can also use CSS for the same purpose instead of writing extra Java code.

Comment: @Colin, That is an Awesome answer, I just tested & it works very well, so simple so elegant. Thank you very much

Comment: @AndreiVolgin dead on, I just started with the simple one liners.